# using linux bash shell script with awscli to script creation and deletion of app load balancers

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I want to create a bash shell script that will find my specific aws loadbalancer and target group "arns" that all have the ZZQA pattern in them so that I can delete them all after creating multiple ones.

I have to query with a awscli command and that returns the results to a var (returns flat file with the arms separated by tabs). Shown in sample below. How can I match on each ZZQA "arn" entry one at a time and delete it?

Sample of the data:
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:975658547626:loadbalancer/app/ApplicationELB/f6d5ecfe31f88a7e arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:975658547626:loadbalancer/app/ZZQAhKGhxZFFFzgVyUKhiEUzbFdrPoCn/8d5f41bbc94ff22

Something like:

```
while :
do
    GetLB=$(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --output text --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerArn')
    $GetLB = $LBARN if $GetLB =~ /\w*ZZQA\w*/g
    aws elbv2 delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-arn $LBARN
    GetTG=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --query 'TargetGroups[*].TargetGroupArn')
    $GetTG = $TGARN if $GetTG =~ /\w*ZZQA\w*/g
    aws elbv2 delete-target-group --target-group-arn $TGARN
done
```

Comment: Any reason why you opted for a shell script? These things can be easily done with Java or Python API for AWS.

Comment: the sample seems to bash, but some lines are in perl

Answer (score 0):

One possible awk option would be:

```
awk -F\(arn\:\) '{ for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( index($i,"ZZQA") > 0  ) print $i } }' <<< $var
```

Where var contain the text outlined.

We first set up the field delimiter to be arn: and then go through each delimited field checking against "ZZQA". If the text is there, the arn is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the following for the load balancers at least:

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --output json --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerArn' | 
  grep "arn.*ZZQA" | 
  sed "s/[,\" ]//g" |
  xargs aws elbv2 delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-arn
```

This will query for the load balancer arns and then pipe them to the delete call.

If this works, it should be fairly easy to do the target groups too.